# How to call express to trigger external redirect and avoid CORs

Tags: node.js, ajax, express, cors, shopify

I am trying to trigger an express.js route from the front-end via an ajax call. Once the route is called it redirects to an external redirect to another domain. Every time I run this route I run into a CORs preflight error.

I imagine the ideal workflow would look something like this:

1. User clicks on the subscription button.
2. An AJAX (Jquery) call is sent to the express route (app.get('/shopify/new-charge')).
3. The express route runs.
4. The external redirect is triggered and the user is sent to the other domain.

Through my research I think the issue is with the response coming back from the back-end to the front end.

I have tried implementing the following:

- modifying the AJAX call
- npm CORS in the server.js
- adding headers to the server.js
- adding headers to the ajax
- adding headers to the redirect
- adding a status to the redirect ( res.redirect(301, 'https://external-url.com' )
- adding in next() after the res.redirect()
- whitelisting the origin and the origin with the route

However, I was successful in resolving this conflict by wrapping my button with a form, and eliminating the AJAX call, but I would like to know if this is possible via an AJAX call from the front end.

Front End Ajax Call

```
    activateSubscriptionButton.addEventListener('click', function () {
​
        var newChargeUrl = "/shopify/new-charge;
​
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: newChargeUrl,
            data: {"shop" : test.com},
            success: function (result) {
                console.log('Success - Paid');
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, exception) {
                console.log('Error - No Paid');
                console.log('jqXHR :', jqXHR);
            },
        });
​
    }, false);
```

Express.js Route

```
app.get("/shopify/new-charge", function (req, res, next) {
            const shop_domain = req.query.shop;

            const shopRequestUrl = 'https://' + shop_domain + '/admin/api/2019-04/recurring_application_charges.json';

            const newCharge = {
                "recurring_application_charge": {
                    "name": "Professional Plan",//
                    "price": 4.99,
                    "return_url": forwardingAddress + "\/shopify\/billing\/activate?shop=" + encodeURIComponent(shop_domain),
                    "test": true,
                }
            };
                    request.post(shopRequestUrl,
                        {
                            headers: {
                                'X-Shopify-Access-Token': access_token,
                            },
                            json: newCharge
                        }, function (error, response, body) {
                            if (error) {
                                console.error('Error has occurred with charge: ', error);
                                return
                            }
                            else {
                                // Redirect User To External Confirmation Page//
                                res.redirect('https://external-url.com/');
                            }
                        })   
            else {
                res.send('Error: No shop_domain.');
            }
        });
```

Server.js

```
        var express = require("express");
        var app = express();
        var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
        const forwardingAddress = process.env.ngrok_forwarding_address;

        app.use(express.static("public"));
        app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
        app.use(bodyParser.json());
        app.use(bodyParser.text());

        require("./controllers/shopify")(app);
        require("./controllers/billing")(app);

        // Setting up port and requiring models for syncing
        var PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;

        app.listen(PORT, function () {
            console.log("Server listening on: http://localhost:" + PORT);
        });
```

Below is the error I receive when I run the above code:

OPTIONS: https://external-url.com 404

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://external-url.com' (redirected from 'https://local.ngrok.com/shopify/new-charge?shop=test.com') from origin 'https://local.ngrok.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesnt pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow_Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Is there a way to accomplish my goal by modifying the existing code presented above?

Comment: Your code doesn't show any code that attempts to access `https://external-url.com/` which is apparently the URL that is causing the problem.  So, we can't see what code is leading to the problem.  Where is that happening?  The Ajax call you show appears to be local to the page domain not to `https://external-url.com/`.

Comment: @jfriend00 I condensed the code. The 'https://external-url.com/' is now located towards the bottom of the Express.js Route code snippet. Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: So the Ajax call gets redirected to another domain???

Comment: @epascarello I'm trying to use AJAX to call the endpoint and then at the end of the endpoint I want it to do an external redirect.

Answer (score 0):

You are really missing out on a fundamental feature of Shopify here. With regards to your App, go into your App setup in your Partner account and for that App create an App Proxy call. The endpoint you create is then what you call from the front-end with your JS code. Shopify ensures security, and all your CORS problems go away. This is why the App Proxy exists, to allow front-end calls to be securely made to back-end Apps.

**TL:DR; Your front-end pattern is doomed, and you should re-factor to use secure App Proxy.**

Comment: Hahah Thanks David. You are always insightful with your information regarding Shopify. So if I set the App Proxy to 'apps/new-charge', proxy URL 'https://hosted.domain.com' then I would call 'apps/new-charge' in my ajax call?

Comment: Study App Proxy. It is not too much to get started with buy following their examples.